# How can I add an SSL certificate to my already existing node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, keystonejs

I have a node.js server made with keystone.js, but before launching it I need to add an SSL certificate. All the examples and tutorials I've seen to add an SSL certificate to a node.js server only show how to create a new https server from scratch.

I already have my entire application and api working off http, is there a simple way to make it all work on https?

Comment: I don't know keystone.js (so forgive me if this is already implicitly covered in your question), but have you tried [setting Keystone's HTTPS options](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#options-ssl)? Or do you also need instructions on how to generate a new SSL key/certificate, in addition to how to use that certificate within keystone.js?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think you need to do this without restarting the application; it's a pretty low cost thing to do.

That said, the simplest approach would be to put up an Nginx web server in front of it, and then setup the Nginx server as the https endpoint and proxypass the requests forward to your node process.